# An anonymous "free space" is showing in the disks window

Tags: disk, partitioning, format, delete

I want to have only 2 partitions: the 238GB as shown in the picture, and the 262GB, But there is an anonymous "Free space 2.1MB" is coming from somewhere I don't know.
I don't know how to merge it with the 262GB free space because it should be coming from there not from the 238GB Part; Mean: the 2.1MB should be a part from the 262GB partition, but I'm not sure.

On the another window (the installation type window) it's showing that I have only 2 partitions.

I don't know which window I should believe.
But I want to get rid of this 2.1MB in some way.

But I don't want to lose the data stored in the 238GB partition

[image: Installation type window]
[image: Disks window: anonymous free space]
[image: Disks window: 238GB]
[image]

Comment: Consider whether regaining a relatively tiny 2 MB area is worth the risk. You do only have 2 partitions, the 2 MB is unallocated space.

Comment: if it's something easy I'll do, or I'll leave it as it is

Comment: what does the unallocated space mean?

Comment: It just means when the partitions were created there was a tiny bit of the disk left unused. I don't know why it happens but it happens almost every time. It's ~2 MB out of ~600 GB.

Comment: The 2Mb is a boundary., Those are created to have a partition start on an exact number. You will likely see one in between any partition when using EFI. Normal and unavoidable.

Comment: @Rinzwind ^^ see above.

Comment: i got enough rep >:=D someone else can go for it